# AngularJS display list from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, list, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller that returns an array, I'm trying to display every element of that array as a list.

What I am attempting to do, which is not working:

```
<li ng-repeat="Name in names">
    <a ng-controller="PostsCtrl" href="#">{{response.text}}</a>
</li>
```

*response.text* returns an array from the controller.

I am also wondering, what is the value of the ng-repeat attribute supposed to be, any unique string?

Thank you!

Comment: What does `names` and `response` look like? I know you mention an array but are both of them an array?

Comment: How about {{ JSON.stringify(response.text) }} ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Define the array in your controller with the $scope variable:

```
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.response = { text: ['hello', 'world'] };
}
```

Then use ng-repeat on the VARIABLE, not the controller.

```
<div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in response.text"><a href="#">{{name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The controller is only used to define what $scope variables you can use in that section, and is not used as a variable itself.

Answer (score 3):

`ngRepeat` is basically just like a `for` loop. There is no default value, you just need to give it the data you want it to iterate through. So when you're doing a `ng-repeat="name in names"`, it is similar to doing something like `for(var name in names){}` in plain javascript. For it to work properly you need to pass this data to the template via your `$scope`, as such:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    // Here the array would be your response.text:
    $scope.names = ['John', 'Jessie', 'Johanna', 'Joy', 'Mary', 'Peter', 'Sebastian', 'Erika', 'Patrick', 'Samantha'];

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
        I have {{names.length}} friends. They are:
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="name in names">
            [{{$index + 1}}] {{name}}.
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

For further reading, please visit: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry that I can't select multiple correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your controller on the wrong attribute there, unless you want a new controller for every item in the array.

The second issue, "`response.text` returns an array from the controller."  So, is this the array you want to repeat?

```
<div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="item in response.text">
      <a href="#">{{item}}</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

And then the third question, what is the value of the `ng-repeat` attribute supposed to be: it's supposed to be the value of any valid array on your `$scope` or `viewModel`.  So, `response.text` would be a valid item to put on the `ng-repeat` since it is an array.  As I have it above, you now have an `item` object for every item in `reponse.text`.  If this is as far down as you want to go, you can simply print `{{item}}` -- if `item` has properties, you could do something like, for instance, `{{item.someProperty}}`

Comment: Thank you, too bad I can't select multiple correct answers!